# Swap Order of table rows but keep Zebra Striping

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a small `jQuery` function where I can swap rows by clicking on an up arrow or a down arrow.  The row swap works perfectly.  What I can't figure out is why my handling of the striping colors is not working.  Here is an example if you click the "up" arrow.

```
    // =================================
    // UP & DOWN (Ordering) Arrows
    // =================================            
    $(".row-up").click(function() {

        var thisRow     = $(this).closest("tr");
        var thisRowBG   = $(thisRow).css("background");

        var aboveRow    = $(this).closest("tr").prev("tr"); 
        var aboveRowBG  = $(aboveRow).css("background");    

        $(thisRow).after($(aboveRow));

        // switch zebra colors
        $(aboveRow).css("background", thisRowBG);   
        $(thisRow).css("background", aboveRowBG);

    });
```

With this code, the colors are not swapping. As you see, I am trying to save the instances of the two rows involve in the swap and then switch them.  This needs to work in IE8.

**EDIT:**

The CSS for the colored rows is this:

```
.st_lr_r1 {
    background-color: #DEEAF1;
}
```

the "white" row (`.st_lr_r0`) has no color applied.

Comment: How is the striping applied?

Comment: I will add that.. one moment...

Comment: If you will use simple css selectors like :nth-child(odd/even) this will never be an issue

Comment: What about using :nth-child(odd) and :nth-child(even) selectors, do those move when the row gets resorted? Might need a jsfiddle to test this. Ha, @UtherTG just beat me to it.

Comment: I am just a single minion on a large project and have to work around other's programming.  I can't change those things.   So I have to be more imaginative.  Maybe I just need to check if row has class `st_lr_r1` and if so add and remove.

Comment: If you are using jquery purely to control css you can enter a world of pain, but I have added an answer with a jquery solution that might work, but it needs testing.

Comment: @UtherTG  That doesn't work on IE8 which is why I probably won't be doing that.

Comment: @KickingLettuce you're correct, but you didn't specify browser support. Then jquery answer below is your friend. Just remember that you need to call that after you changed table. If you want to use it from $(this), then try $(this).closest('table').find('tr:odd').css('background-color', '#deeaf1');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare `even` and `odd` directly in CSS instead of relying on JS to do it.

```
table > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9doy3xbu/)**

IE8?

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('st_lr_r0');
    $('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('st_lr_r1');
});
```

**[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uw4v9gv4/)**

Yes, using the same selector through jQuery will work with IE8. :)

Comment: And is this supported cross browser including IE8?

Comment: You didn't specify browser support. See updated answer in a sec!

Comment: Apologies; I just added that a moment ago.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great; I just had to also do a `removeClass` so my version is four lines.

Answer (score 2):

How about this then (needs testing)

```
$( "tr:odd" ).css( "background-color", "#DEEAF1" );
```

I lifted this straight from the jquery odd selector page. Obviously you can modify it to suit your needs.

http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Comment: Vote up for that answer. First of all it's clean. Also used correct css. But I strongly suggest to modify css files instead

Comment: That does seem like a perfect answer.  It doesn't seem to be working as I am testing, but by the looks of it, it absolutely seems like it should.  Let me keep testing...